# How to hide a node from appearing on menu not on breadcrumb (using SqlSiteMapProvider)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlsitemapprovider

I am using [wicked code sqlsitemapprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx) or [it's VB version](http://sanjayuttam.com/wordpress/index.php/asp-net/sqlsitemapprovider-in-vb-net/). Most of the things are going OK! But when I wanted to hide some of the nodes from appearing on menu while staying shown on sitemappath I cannot figure it out. I tried to change the sqlsitemapprovider code but was unsuccessfull. I have found [David Sussman's](http://forums.asp.net/t/1063701.aspx#1534197) (from sp.net) answer. but it was for a .sitemap file. So how can I manage to do the same with the sql sitemap provider mentioned above.

I added a column named visible to my SiteMap table it's type is bit and then I have done these changes (Sorry for such long code):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration.Provider
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Caching

''' <summary>
''' Summary description for SqlSiteMapProvider
''' </summary>
<SqlClientPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted:=True)> _
Public Class SqlSiteMapProvider
    Inherits StaticSiteMapProvider
    Private Const _errmsg1 As String = "Basamak no bulunamadı"
    Private Const _errmsg2 As String = "Çift Basamak No"
    Private Const _errmsg3 As String = "Üst Basamak Bulunamadı"
    Private Const _errmsg4 As String = "Hatalı Üst Basamak"
    Private Const _errmsg5 As String = "Bağlantı dizesi bulunamadı veya boş"
    Private Const _errmsg6 As String = "Bağlantı dizesi bulunamadı"
    Private Const _errmsg7 As String = "Bağlantı dizesi boş"
    Private Const _errmsg8 As String = "Hatalı sqlCacheDependency"
    Private Const _cacheDependencyName As String = "__SiteMapCacheDependency"


    Private _connect As String
    'Database connection string
    Private _database As String, _table As String
    'Database info for SQL Server 7/2000 cache dependency
    Private _2005dependency As Boolean = False
    'Database info for SQL Server 2005 cache dependency
    Private _indexID As Integer, _indexTitle As Integer, _indexUrl As Integer, _indexDesc As Integer, _indexRoles As Integer, _indexParent As Integer, _indexvisible As Boolean
    Private _nodes As New Dictionary(Of Integer, SiteMapNode)(16)
    Private ReadOnly _lock As New Object()
    Private _root As SiteMapNode
    'Added...Declare an arraylist to hold all the roles this menu item applies to
    Public roles As New ArrayList



    Public Overloads Overrides Sub Initialize(ByVal name As String, ByVal config As NameValueCollection)

        'Verify that config isn't null
        If config Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("config")
        End If

        'Assign the provider a default name if it doesn't have one
        If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Name) Then
            Name = "SqlSiteMapProvider"
        End If

        ' Add a default "description" attribute to config if the
        ' attribute doesnt exist or is empty
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(config("description")) Then
            config.Remove("description")
            config.Add("description", "SQL site map provider")
        End If

        ' Call the base class's Initialize method
        MyBase.Initialize(Name, config)

        ' Initialize _connect
        Dim connect As String = config("connectionStringName")

        If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(connect) Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg5)
        End If

        config.Remove("connectionStringName")

        If WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connect) Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg6)
        End If

        _connect = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connect).ConnectionString

        If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(_connect) Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg7)
        End If

        ' Initialize SQL cache dependency info
        Dim dependency As String = config("sqlCacheDependency")

        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(dependency) Then
            If [String].Equals(dependency, "CommandNotification", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                SqlDependency.Start(_connect)
                _2005dependency = True
            Else
                ' If not "CommandNotification", then extract database and table names
                Dim info As String() = dependency.Split(New Char() {":"c})
                If info.Length <> 2 Then
                    Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg8)
                End If

                _database = info(0)
                _table = info(1)
            End If

            config.Remove("sqlCacheDependency")
        End If

        ' SiteMapProvider processes the securityTrimmingEnabled
        ' attribute but fails to remove it. Remove it now so we can
        ' check for unrecognized configuration attributes.

        If config("securityTrimmingEnabled") IsNot Nothing Then
            config.Remove("securityTrimmingEnabled")
        End If

        ' Throw an exception if unrecognized attributes remain
        If config.Count > 0 Then
            Dim attr As String = config.GetKey(0)
            If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(attr) Then
                Throw New ProviderException("Unrecognized attribute: " + attr)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Overrides Function BuildSiteMap() As SiteMapNode
        SyncLock _lock
            ' Return immediately if this method has been called before
            If _root IsNot Nothing Then
                Return _root
            End If

            ' Query the database for site map nodes
            Dim connection As New SqlConnection(_connect)

            Try
                Dim command As New SqlCommand("proc_GetSiteMap", connection)
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                ' Create a SQL cache dependency if requested
                Dim dependency As SqlCacheDependency = Nothing

                If _2005dependency Then
                    dependency = New SqlCacheDependency(command)
                ElseIf Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(_database) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_table) Then
                    dependency = New SqlCacheDependency(_database, _table)
                End If

                connection.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                _indexID = reader.GetOrdinal("ID")
                _indexUrl = reader.GetOrdinal("Url")
                _indexTitle = reader.GetOrdinal("Title")
                _indexDesc = reader.GetOrdinal("Description")
                _indexRoles = reader.GetOrdinal("Roles")
                _indexParent = reader.GetOrdinal("Parent")
                _indexvisible = reader.GetOrdinal("visible")

                If reader.Read() Then
                    ' Create the root SiteMapNode and add it to the site map
                    _root = CreateSiteMapNodeFromDataReader(reader)
                    AddNode(_root, Nothing)

                    ' Build a tree of SiteMapNodes underneath the root node
                    While reader.Read()
                        ' Create another site map node and add it to the site map
                        Dim node As SiteMapNode = CreateSiteMapNodeFromDataReader(reader)
                        AddNode(node, GetParentNodeFromDataReader(reader))
                    End While

                    ' Use the SQL cache dependency
                    If dependency IsNot Nothing Then
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(_cacheDependencyName, New Object(), dependency, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _
                         New CacheItemRemovedCallback(AddressOf OnSiteMapChanged))
                    End If
                End If
            Finally
                connection.Close()
            End Try

            ' Return the root SiteMapNode
            Return _root
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Protected Overloads Overrides Function GetRootNodeCore() As SiteMapNode
        SyncLock _lock
            BuildSiteMap()
            Return _root
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    ' Helper methods
    Private Function CreateSiteMapNodeFromDataReader(ByVal reader As DbDataReader) As SiteMapNode
        ' Make sure the node ID is present
        If reader.IsDBNull(_indexID) Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg1)
        End If

        ' Get the node ID from the DataReader
        Dim id As Integer = reader.GetInt32(_indexID)

        ' Make sure the node ID is unique
        If _nodes.ContainsKey(id) Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg2)
        End If

        ' Get title, URL, description, and roles from the DataReader
        Dim title As String = IIf(reader.IsDBNull(_indexTitle), Nothing, reader.GetString(_indexTitle).Trim())
        'Dim url As String = IIf(reader.IsDBNull(_indexUrl), Nothing, reader.GetString(_indexUrl).Trim())

        'Dim url As String = ReplaceNullRefs(reader, _indexUrl)
        Dim url As String = String.Empty
        If Not (reader.IsDBNull(_indexUrl)) Then
            url = reader.GetString(_indexUrl).Trim()
        Else
            url = ""
        End If

        'Eliminated...see http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2003/10/09/31250.aspx
        'Dim description As String = IIf(reader.IsDBNull(_indexDesc), Nothing, reader.GetString(_indexDesc).Trim())
        'Added line below and 'ReplaceNUllRefs' func
        Dim description As String = ReplaceNullRefs(reader, _indexDesc)

        'Changed variable name from 'roles' to 'rolesN' and added line 230 to dump all roles into an arrayList
        Dim rolesN As String = IIf(reader.IsDBNull(_indexRoles), Nothing, reader.GetString(_indexRoles).Trim())


        Dim rolelist As String() = Nothing
        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(rolesN) Then
            rolelist = rolesN.Split(New Char() {","c, ";"c}, 512)
        End If
        roles = ArrayList.Adapter(rolelist)

        Dim visible As Boolean = ReplaceNullRefs(reader, _indexvisible)
        ' Create a SiteMapNode
        Dim node As New SiteMapNode(Me, id.ToString(), url, title, description, rolelist, _
         Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)

        ' Record the node in the _nodes dictionary
        _nodes.Add(id, node)

        ' Return the node        
        Return node
    End Function

    Private Function ReplaceNullRefs(ByVal rdr As SqlDataReader, ByVal rdrVal As Integer) As String
        If Not (rdr.IsDBNull(rdrVal)) Then
            Return rdr.GetString(rdrVal)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetParentNodeFromDataReader(ByVal reader As DbDataReader) As SiteMapNode
        ' Make sure the parent ID is present
        If reader.IsDBNull(_indexParent) Then
            '**** Commented out throw, added exit function ****
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg3)
            'Exit Function
        End If

        ' Get the parent ID from the DataReader
        Dim pid As Integer = reader.GetInt32(_indexParent)

        ' Make sure the parent ID is valid
        If Not _nodes.ContainsKey(pid) Then
            Throw New ProviderException(_errmsg4)
        End If

        ' Return the parent SiteMapNode
        Return _nodes(pid)
    End Function

    Private Sub OnSiteMapChanged(ByVal key As String, ByVal item As Object, ByVal reason As CacheItemRemovedReason)
        SyncLock _lock
            If key = _cacheDependencyName AndAlso reason = CacheItemRemovedReason.DependencyChanged Then
                ' Refresh the site map
                Clear()
                _nodes.Clear()
                _root = Nothing
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

and I get this error:

```
*Özel Durum Ayrıntıları: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: visible

Kaynak Hatası:

Satır 154:                _indexRoles = reader.GetOrdinal("Roles")

Satır 155:                _indexParent = reader.GetOrdinal("Parent")

Satır 156:                _indexvisible = reader.GetOrdinal("visible")

Satır 157:

Satır 158:                If reader.Read() Then

Kaynak Dosya: D:\Websites\kaihl\App_Code\SqlSiteMapProvider.vb    Satır: 156*
```

What I want is to tell sqlsitemapprovider to include an attribute within each sitemapnode called visible="true/false". Since this will be an extra attribute for sitemappath and menu (I think) this code would be doing the hiding job in menu not in breadcrumb (according to David Sussman's reply to a similar files .sitemap based thread as I linked above in my question):

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemDataBound  
    Dim node As SiteMapNode = CType(e.Item.DataItem, SiteMapNode)  
    ' check for the visible attribute and if false  
    ' remove the node from the parent  
    ' this allows nodes to appear in the SiteMapPath but not show on the menu  
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(node("visible")) Then  
        Dim isVisible As Boolean  
        If Boolean.TryParse(node("visible"), isVisible) Then  
            If Not isVisible Then  
                e.Item.Parent.ChildItems.Remove(e.Item)  
            End If  
        End If  
    End If  
End Sub
```

how to achieve this? thank you.

Update: I have found something very close a[t this page](http://forums.asp.net/p/1342322/2721906.aspx#2720464)  but still unable to deploy the solution.

```
Dim atts As NameValueCollection = Nothing
    Dim attributeString As String = reader("attributes").ToString().Trim()
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(attributeString) Then
        atts = New NameValueCollection()
        Dim attributePairs() As String = attributeString.Split(";")
        For Each attributePair As String In atts
            Dim attributes() As String = attributePair.Split(":")
            If attributes.Length = 2 Then
                atts.Add(atts(0), attributes(1))
            End If
        Next
    End If

  Dim node As New SiteMapNode(Me, id.ToString(), url, title, description, rolelist, _
    atts, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have found a solution. And it is [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1608879/4110806.aspx#4110806). Thanks so much to [Kadir ÖZGÜR](http://www.kadirozgur.com/en), Sanjay UTTAM, David Sussman.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [link](http://www.ishaihachlili.com/webdev/2006/09/sql-sitemap-provider-and-trimming-by.html). he overides the IsAccessibleToUser property on the SiteMapprovider to selectivly show nodes based on the role of the current user. you caould change the condiftion to suit your needs.

Comment: I already added the functionality to apply membership but I am examining the code . But I think that sitemapprovider should send that the visible attribute to the sitemap so that the Menu1_MenuItemDataBound sub sees it and decides whether to show or remove the respective node. thanks for the answer nothwithstanding.

Comment: http://www.ishaihachlili.com/webdev/2006/09/sql-sitemap-provider-and-trimming-by.html not found